# Non greedy parsing with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a line with pyparsing. This line is composed of a number of (key, values). What I'd like to get is a list of (key, values). A simple example:

```
ids = 12 fields = name
```

should result in something like:  `[('ids', '12'), ('fields', 'name')]`

A more complex example:

```
ids = 12, 13, 14 fields = name, title
```

should result in something like:  `[('ids', '12, 13, 14'), ('fields', 'name, title')]`

PS: the tuple inside the resulting list is just an example. It could be a dict or another list or whatever, it's not that important.

But whatever I've tried up to now I get results like:
`[('ids', '12 fields')]`

Pyparsing is eating the next key, considering it's also part of the value.

Here is a sample code:

```
import pyparsing as P

key = P.oneOf("ids fields")
equal = P.Literal('=')
key_equal = key + equal
val = ~key_equal + P.Word(P.alphanums+', ')

gr = P.Group(key_equal+val)
print gr.parseString("ids = 12 fields = name")
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem lies in this line:

```
val = ~key_equal + P.Word(P.alphanums+', ')
```

It suggests that the part matches any alphanumeric sequence, followed by the literal `', '`, but instead it matches any sequence of alphanumeric characters, `','` and `' '`.

What you'd want instead is:

```
val = ~key_equal + P.delimitedList(P.Word(P.alphanums), ", ", combine=True)
```

The second problem is that you only parse one key-value pair:

```
gr = P.Group(key_equal+val)
```

Instead, you should parse as many as possible:

```
gr = P.Group(P.OneOrMore(key_equal+val))
```

So the correct solution is:

```
>>> import pyparsing as P
>>> key = P.oneOf("ids fields")
>>> equal = P.Literal('=')
>>> key_equal = key + equal
>>> val = ~key_equal + P.delimitedList(P.Word(P.alphanums), ", ", combine=True)
>>> gr = P.OneOrMore(P.Group(key_equal+val))
>>> print gr.parseString("ids = 12, 13, 14 fields = name, title")
[['ids', '=', '12, 13, 14'], ['fields', '=', 'name, title']]
```

Comment: PS: slightly edited your post. I get a better result with your solution. The problem is that I only get the first part and not the following parts. I get [('ids', '12,13,14')]. I'd like to get [('ids', '12,13,14'), ('fields', 'name,title')]

Comment: @Oli: Thanks for the catch. I added the solution to your second problem.

Comment: @Oli: Beware, I made a slight mistake in the version you commented on. (It puts everything in the same list, instead of grouping the individual pairs). This problem is now fixed.